# How to configure Spring Cloud Zipkin server with Elasticsearch for persistence?

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, cloud, zipkin

I want to load my Spring Cloud zipkin-server with elasticsearch.
I think, I tried almost everything I could.
but, It still running with in-memory.
(when I restart zipkin-server, all data is lost.)
I want to set up zipkin with elasticsearch.
Please tell me which exact **dependencies** and **applicartion.yml** or any other things needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating custom zipkin servers is an unsupported configuration, but if you must all of the configuration options are documented in the project readme: https://github.com/openzipkin/zipkin/blob/master/zipkin-server/README.md

Answer (score 1):

For the dependencies part, the most important one is **zipkin-autoconfigure-storage-elasticsearch-http**, here's an full maven pom.xml example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>zipkin-server</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>zipkin-server</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <spring-cloud.version>Dalston.SR1</spring-cloud.version>
    <zipkin.version>1.23.2</zipkin.version>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.zipkin.java</groupId>
        <artifactId>zipkin-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.zipkin.java</groupId>
        <artifactId>zipkin-autoconfigure-ui</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.zipkin.java</groupId>
        <artifactId>zipkin-autoconfigure-collector-kafka10</artifactId>
        <version>1.26.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-sleuth-zipkin-stream</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.zipkin.java</groupId>
        <artifactId>zipkin-autoconfigure-storage-elasticsearch-http</artifactId>
        <version>${zipkin.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

For the configuration part, you will need the following in you **application.yml**:

```
zipkin:
  storage:
    type: elasticsearch
    elasticsearch:
      hosts: localhost:9200
```

Answer (score 0):

I configured zipkin to use ES as a data storage on top of kubernetes. If it fits your requirement feel free to download and use https://github.com/handysofts/zipkin-on-kubernetes